# distinct-values() in return result does not work?

Tags: xquery

I am a newbie in XQuery, and My problem is about distinct values, I am using the following codes to retrieving movie reviewers

```
xquery version "1.0";
declare boundary-space preserve;
<result>
{for $reviews in doc("reviews.xml")/reviews/review,
     $movie in doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie
 where $reviews/movie_title = $movie/movie_title
   and $movie//movie_genre = "Drama"
   and $movie//month > 6
 order by $reviews/movie_reviewer descending
 return
(<reviewer>{distinct-values($reviews/movie_reviewer)}</reviewer>, '&#xa;')
 }
 </result>
```

and later I change the code to

```
xquery version "1.0";
declare boundary-space preserve;
<result>
{for $reviews in doc("reviews.xml")/reviews/review,
     $movie in doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie
 where $reviews/movie_title = $movie/movie_title
   and $movie//movie_genre = "Drama"
   and $movie//month > 6
 return
{for $content in distinct-values($reviews/movie_reviewer)
      order by $content descending
      return (<reviewer>{$content}</reviewer>, '&#xa;')}
 }
 </result>
```

but I got the similar result as

```
 <result>
 <reviewer>Wesley Barry</reviewer>
 <reviewer>Michael Gordon</reviewer>
 <reviewer>Michael Gordon</reviewer>
 <reviewer>Michael Gordon</reviewer>
 <reviewer>John Frankenheimer</reviewer>
 <reviewer>J. Lee Thompson</reviewer>
 <reviewer>J. Lee Thompson</reviewer>
 <reviewer>Charles Walters</reviewer>
 <reviewer>Charles Walters</reviewer>
 </result>
```

how can I make the result like

```
<result>
 <reviewer>Wesley Barry</reviewer>
 <reviewer>Michael Gordon</reviewer>
 <reviewer>John Frankenheimer</reviewer>
 <reviewer>J. Lee Thompson</reviewer>
 <reviewer>Charles Walters</reviewer>
 </result>
```

?
I know this is quite basic, but I just can't get the point

Comment: Please post data, eg. on [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com/) (and add it to your question)! Telling what's wrong heavily depends on the structure of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow @Ranon's advice. However, guessing from your query: The easiest way would be if you could use XQuery 3.0 and the new group-by-statement.

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare boundary-space preserve;
<result>
{for $reviews in doc("reviews.xml")/reviews/review,
     $movie in doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie
 let $reviewer := $reviews/movie_reviewer
 where $reviews/movie_title = $movie/movie_title
   and $movie//movie_genre = "Drama"
   and $movie//month > 6
 group by $reviewer
 order by $reviewer descending
 return
(<reviewer>{$reviewer}</reviewer>, '&#xa;')
 }
 </result>
```